# How to disable global menu and have always visible menu bars

Tags: menu

Is it possible to get menus to be shown in always visible menu bars in 14.04, rather than in window title bars?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you should remove some packages. Use:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge appmenu-gtk appmenu-gtk3 appmenu-qt firefox-globalmenu thunderbird-globalmenu indicator-appmenu
```

This will restore application menus in right place.

UPD: there might be a few packages I missed. To find them, open Synaptic and in the search field enter "appmenu", check the found packages for removal, then search for "globalmenu" and remove them too.

Restart/relogin into your X session to finish changes.

Also check [this article](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/11/unity-global-menu-can-now-be-disabled.html).

Comment: This does not seem to work for nautilus.

Comment: See the updated answer for instructions.

Comment: blacklisting is something you would do if the package is installed, did you actually restore the nautilus menu bar?

Comment: No, I just want to give you more options to try.

Comment: Worked perfectly on Xubuntu 14.04 - finally I have my menu bars back. :)

Comment: doesnt work for firefox or chrome in Gnome-flashback 14.04

Comment: @KalamalkaKid AFAIK Firefox and Chrome do not have menu bar at all.

Comment: I went back to unity after not being able resolve  many issues in gnome. Too buggy.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simpler method. Just type

```
sudo apt-get remove hud
```

in Terminal. It will remove all the other packages and you will get what you want.

Comment: This does not seem to work. Using `apt remove --purge hud` will only remove `hud` on Ubuntu 14.04, not any other packages. Are you sure?