# is it possible to have an always visible menu bar for nautilus or restore the default full gear button menu, in 14.04

Tags: nautilus, 14.04, menu, appmenu, menu-bar

The [general solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/441421) which involves uninstalling various appmenu packages does not work for nautilus, its menu bar is still missing.

It does get a gear drop down menu button on the tool bar, but that menu is missing many menu items (e.g. preferences)

If a menu bar is not part of the default nautilus interface, then how do you at least get the full gear button menu.

Answer (score 0):

In previeous versions of Ubuntu, the Nautilus menubar was simply hidden in order to move the menubar into the panel. So if you deactivated that feature, then the menubar would reappear. But now, Gnome is moving away from the concept of menubars in general, and this includes apps like Nautilus. Nautilus simply doesn't have a menubar anymore. The only thing Unity hides now, is the cog-button to display the menu that isn't useful because Unity displays menubars even though Nautilus doesn't have one.

In Ubuntu, developers have added support for "shell menus" by exposing the actions over DBus so that Unity itself can draw menubars and support HUD. In other words, if you wanted to have a permanently visible menubar for Nautilus in Ubuntu, you'd most likely have to customize Unity itself. This might be difficult, but it should be possible. You wouldn't get the menubar within the application itself, but you might be able to make it so that the menu was always visible on the window decorator and the title was always visible on the top panel.

And of course, you have the opportunity to change Nautilus itself.

But I guess these aren't the kinds of answers you were looking for. To most people, the answer would be "no, you can't get a permanently visible menubar in Nautilus". We do have many file managers to choose from though.

Also remember that if you press <kbd>Alt</kbd>, then the menubar becomes visible, so if you have the menubar on the window itself, you might get used to simply pressing it when you need the menus to be visible.

Comment: restoring the default nautilus interface would be sufficient, which I take it is just the gear button and menu, but as I mentioned, the general solution does not restore the the full gear button menu, there are items missing

Comment: Yes, because it has been removed from the software. It isn't simply hidden by Ubuntu. There is no longer a menubar to hide. It's now designed to look like this: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/28/Nautilus-3.10.0.png

Comment: so then how do you restore the default, full gear button menu?

Comment: Many items have been removed from that menu, which Ubuntu has re-added. You'll need to use the Unity appmenu stuff to get to them.

Comment: Are you saying the default nautilus gear menu does not have a preferences item?  Doubtful.

Comment: No, you didn't mention anything specific, so I was speaking in general.

Comment: You could use `nemo`, a fork from nautilus where they kept back most of the nautilus' changes towards unity, such as the menubar. It's in the regular repositories and can be used as a drop-in replacement for nautilus.