# Locally Integrated Menus - ALWAYS visible?

Tags: unity, gnome, 14.10, menu, 15.04

I'm reading that [Ubuntu 15.04 will have Locally Integrated Menus](http://news.softpedia.com/news/Ubuntu-15-04-to-Get-Locally-Integrated-Menus-by-Default-473888.shtml):

> integrated directly in the title bar and not in the system's top bar. This means that users have faster access to the menus, **and they don't increase the size of the window.** (emphasis mine)

I've never liked the old way of having the menus in the top bar, so this is a welcome change. But my gripe is with the latter part -- **I want to have the menus visible** ***always!*** In my point of view, hiding very basic functionality is a gross usability violation.

--> What can I do to make **ALL** menus visible **ALL** the time in **ALL** programs?

I'm currently running plain Ubuntu 14.10 but I could upgrade to 15.04 if that gets me always-visible menus.

The best information I could find was [4 years old](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25785/can-auto-hide-for-the-application-menu-be-turned-off-in-unity) so I'd be happy about any newer details! I have seen [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/441421/how-to-disable-global-menu-and-have-always-visible-menu-bars) too but it doesn't seem to work: in most programs I still need to hover over the window title to reveal the menu.

Answer (score 1):

For 14.10 there will never be the ability to have locally integrated menus always visible - at least, not without you hacking Unity code yourself.

15.04 included this ability to always switch on.  14.04 (since this being the LTS version), had this ability backported.

Thus you have three choices:

1. stick to 14.10 for the period of its support.
2. Move on up to 15.04 where menus are now permanently visible by default, or
3. Move back to 14.04 where this has been backported (see related questions below).

---

#### Related Questions

- [How do I always show menu items in Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/541449/14-04-always-show-menu-items)
- [Can auto-hide for the application menu be turned off in Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25785/can-auto-hide-for-the-application-menu-be-turned-off-in-unity)

Comment: Thank you! I'll go with option #2 (and accept when I see it working).

Answer (score 0):

```
apt-get autoremove appmenu-gtk appmenu-gtk3 appmenu-qt
```

If you use Firefox, you also should deactivate the Addon "Unity Desktop Integration" from within Firefox.

Comment: Sorry but I already did that. And yet, all apps require me to hover over the window title bar to reveal the menus. Chrome, Terminal, Gedit, ...

Comment: I'm sorry that it didn't work for you. I never actually used the command myself because I like the menu-integrated-in-window-bar thing, I only heard about it in a Youtube video and passed it along. It seems to have stopped working at some point. I don't know anything else about this.